# Adding ? to regex subgroup prevents match success in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I'm using a regex in Scala to extract subdomain and folder information from urls as well as to look for the presence of a particular target string anywhere after the first folder. If the target string isn't detected, I still want my regex to match so that I can extract the domain and subdomain. When using a regex that looks like this:

```
val regex1 = "^https?://([^/]+\\.)?domain\\.com(/([^/]+).*(target).*)?".r
```

it seems to correctly match a sample url:

```
val url = "https://domain.com/folder/target/morestuff"
```

however, when I add a ? to the target group, as in:

```
val regex2 = "^https?://([^/]+\\.)?domain\\.com(/([^/]+).*(target)?.*)?".r
```

the match fails to detect my target.

```
scala> url match { case regex1(w, x, y, z) => Some(w, x, y, z) case _ => None }
res43: Option[(String, String, String, String)] = Some((null,/folder/target/morestuff,folder,target)

scala> url match { case regex2(w, x, y, z) => Some(w, x, y, z) case _ => None }
res44: Option[(String, String, String, String)] = Some((null,/folder/target/morestuff,folder,null))
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the evaluation of the .* trailing the target group, but because I want to be able to find my target anywhere it might pop up after the top level folder, I'm not sure how I might dispense with it. I've tried using an unanchored regex instead (dropping the final '.*'), but that didn't work either.

Comment: It is not the trailing `.*` that eats up target part, but the `.*`that is before it. Regex processes the string from left to right and the subpatterns in the pattern are also processed from left to right.

Comment: So, you may use [`^https?://([^/]+\.)?domain\.com(/([^/]+)(?:(?!target).)*(target)?.*)?`](https://regex101.com/r/tMYQ16/1).

Comment: I've actually tried with just the preceding '.*' and just the trailing '.*'. With just the preceding one, I had no issues, but with just the trailing one, my issue persisted. I think it would have made more sense to me if it had been the other way around for the reason you suggested, but that wasn't the case. At any rate, my issue has been resolved now. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if the regex matches without counting parens:

```
scala> url match { case regex2(_*) => }
```

Simplifying to just take repetitions of `/stuff`:

```
scala> val regex2 = raw"https?://([^/]+\.)?domain\.com((/[^/]+)*)".r.unanchored
regex2: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = https?://([^/]+\.)?domain\.com((/[^/]+)*)

scala> url match { case regex2(x, y, z) => (x, y, z) }
res13: (String, String, String) = (null,/folder/target/morestuff,morestuff)
```

Finding the target component:

```
scala> val target = raw"([^/]*target[^/]*)".r.unanchored
target: scala.util.matching.UnanchoredRegex = ([^/]*target[^/]*)

scala> "footargetbar" match { case target(x) => x }
res15: String = footargetbar

scala> url match { case regex2(x, target(y), z) => (x, y, z) }
res16: (String, String, String) = (null,target,morestuff)

scala> url
res17: String = https://domain.com/folder/target/morestuff

scala> val url = "https://domain.com/folder/xtargety/morestuff"
url: String = https://domain.com/folder/xtargety/morestuff

scala> url match { case regex2(x, target(y), z) => (x, y, z) }
res18: (String, String, String) = (null,xtargety,morestuff)
```

You could also write an extractor to split on `/` and look for the pattern in the path elements. The syntax would still look like `target(y)`.

Comment: Thanks! Moving the target matching to a secondary regex helped a lot. Solved the problem I posed, and helped me figure out how to streamline the rest of my matching as well!